# What does GROUP "x" BY "etc" do?

Tags: c#, sql

I couldn't find any help with this kind of query though I searched in MSDN and many books. Maybe someone here will be able to help me. Here's an example:

```
 var query = from document in Database.Documents                           
                       group document.OwnerID by 
                       new 
                       { 
                           OwnerName= document.Owner.OwnerName,
                           ReleaseDate= document.ReleaseDate,
                           OwnerID= document.OwnerID,
                           Status= document.StatusId

                       }
                       into grupo                               
                       select new AmountOfDocuments
                       {
                           OwnerName= grupo.Key.OwnerName,
                           ReleaseDate= grupo.Key.ReleaseDate,
                           OwnerID= grupo.Key.OwnerID,
                           UDocuments= grupo.Count(),
                           SDocuments= grupo.Count()
                       };
```

I need to make UDocuments and SDocuments return the number of documents where status equals either U or S respectively. Help with that will be appreciated but I need to figure out how that query itself works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following code created in Linqpad, it does the job in two different ways and produce the same result. Second one would be preferable as it projects Status as a value of `Grouping` and thus counting becomes simpler

```
void Main()
{
    var testList = Test.Create();

    var result = 
    testList.GroupBy(x=>new {
                          x.OwnerName,
                          x.OwnerId,
                          x.ReleaseDates
                            })
            .Select(y=>new {
                           y.Key.OwnerName,
                           y.Key.OwnerId,
                           statusU = y.Count(m=>m.status == "U"),
                           statusS = y.Count(m=>m.status == "S"),
                            });

    result.Dump();

    var result1 = 
    testList.GroupBy(x=>new {
                          x.OwnerName,
                          x.OwnerId,
                          x.ReleaseDates
                            },x=>x.status)
            .Select(y=>new {
                           y.Key.OwnerName,
                           y.Key.OwnerId,
                           statusU = y.Count(m=>m=="U"),
                           statusS = y.Count(m=>m=="S"),
                            });

    result1.Dump();
}

public class Test
{
    public string OwnerName {get; set;}

    public int OwnerId {get; set;}

    public string status {get; set;}

    public DateTime ReleaseDates{get; set;}

    public static List<Test> Create()
    {
      return new List<Test>()
        {

        new Test
        {
          OwnerName = "ABCD",
          OwnerId = 1,
          status = "S",
          ReleaseDates = DateTime.Now
        },
        new Test
        {
          OwnerName = "ABCD",
          OwnerId = 1,
          status = "S",
          ReleaseDates = DateTime.Now
        },
        new Test
        {
          OwnerName = "ABCD",
          OwnerId = 1,
          status = "S",
          ReleaseDates = DateTime.Now
        },
        new Test
        {
          OwnerName = "ABCD",
          OwnerId = 1,
          status = "U",
          ReleaseDates = DateTime.Now
        },
        new Test
        {
          OwnerName = "ABCD",
          OwnerId = 1,
          status = "U",
          ReleaseDates = DateTime.Now
        },
        new Test
        {
          OwnerName = "ABCD",
          OwnerId = 1,
          status = "S",
          ReleaseDates = DateTime.Now
        }

        };
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions are your friend!

```
UDocuments = grupo.Where(x => x.Status == "U").Count(),
SDocuments = grupo.Where(x => x.Status == "S").Count()
```

Edit: There's no need for the where.

```
UDocuments = grupo.Count(x => x.Status == "U"),
SDocuments = grupo.Count(x => x.Status == "S")
```

Comment: You mean `==` not `=` and `Count` takes a predicate, so more simply, `grupo.Count(x => x.Status == "U")`

Comment: x is being generated as an int variable, not as an AmountOfDocuments one.

Comment: x cannot be an integer until and unless you are projecting an integer value, check that part, in your solution it should be complete object. Check out how to project in the solution created by me

Comment: @Steven Eccles You have acknowledged but not corrected the version with Where, please make the correction it should have ==, in current form its wrong